# Почему не "обеспечЕние", а "обеспЕчение"?

Tags: орфоэпия

На фоне повального стремления в СМИ и рекламе вытеснить русские слова американизмами забавным выглядит упорство дикторов и журналистов произносить слово "обеспечение" с ударением на третий слог, что противоречит законам Русского языка. Я подчеркиваю: противоречит не правилам, написанным конкретными чиновниками от языка, а законам.

Кто-нибудь может объяснить такую уродливую форму ударения?

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, закон русского языка, которому противоречит "обеспЕчение"

Comment: С удовольствием. Закон устойчивых парадигм: в 90-95% форм, оканчивающихся на "-ение" ударение падает на суффикс.

Comment: @Гусляр, если Вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вопросы о правильности ударения интересны уже сами по себе, так как обычно мало кто задумывается о правилах его постановки: как написано в словаре, так и правильно.
Но такие законы существуют, хотя они  не очень известны. И вот нам предоставляется возможность немного поразмышлять на эту тему, чтобы понять постановку ударения в существительных с суффиксами НИ/ЕНИ, образованных от глаголов.

ОБЩИЙ ПРИНЦИП

1) Семантический фактор: надо сохранить  связь с исходным глаголом, чтобы обеспечить семантическую преемственность: желать – желание. 2)  Фонетический фактор: надо обеспечить удобную фонетическую форму, а именно: в многосложных словах рекомендуется постановка ударения ближе к центру слова: мучить – мучение.

ВЛИЯНИЕ СУФФИКСОВ

1). Суффикс НИ: новый гласный не добавляется, поэтому сохраняем ударение  как в глаголе: сиять – сияние,  веять – веяние.

2) Суффикс ЕНИ:  добавляется новый  гласный, ударение смещается к центру на суффикс ЕНИ: уменьшить – уменьшение, изобрести – изобретение, курить – курение, напасть – нападение, ограбить – ограбление.

3) усечение  ударного суффикса ВА: недоумевать – недоумение, подозревать – подозрение, вместо глагольного суффикса ВА ударение падает на суффикс существительного  ЕНИ.

ПАРНЫЕ ВАРИАНТЫ

Парные варианты характерны для многосложных слов, когда действуют два различных фактора. В частности, это следующие слова:  обеспечить – обеспЕчение/обеспечЕние  и обнаружить – обнарУжение/ обнаружЕние, когда допускаются ОБА ВАРИАНТА.

О – бес – пе – че –ни –е, об - на - ру - же - ние -е: в этих  словах центральными являются третий и четвертый слоги, и они могут быть ударными согласно фонетическому фактору. Согласно семантическому фактору, ударение  должно падать на третий слог: обеспЕчить - обеспЕчение, обнарУжить - обнарУжение, но по общему правилу здесь суффикс ЕНИ, так что ударение надо бы сместить на него. Хотя для фонетики это не важно, но  без смещения глагол выпадает из группы себе подобных (уменьшить - уменьшение). Таким образом, действие разных правил приводит к существованию парных форм, но всё-таки форма обеспечЕние выглядит более привлекательной и обоснованной.

СМЫСЛОВОЕ РАЗЛИЧИЕ

Рассмотрим  существительные вИдение (действие)  и видЕние (образ). Они различаются по ударному слогу и никак между собой не конфликтуют. Вот бы и  для слова «обеспечение» применить такой же принцип: обеспечЕние безопасности (действие) и программное обеспЕчение (предмет).

Comment: "Вот бы и для слова «обеспечение» применить такой же принцип: обеспечЕние безопасности (действие) и программное обеспЕчение (предмет)." - Совершенно с Вами согласен и полностью поддерживаю. Великолепный ответ! :-)

Answer (score 5):

> Кто-нибудь может объяснить такую уродливую форму ударения?

Могу. Объянсить эту прекрасную форму ударения.  
Обеспеч**е**ние - это когда вас за неправильную постановку ударения (плохое поведение) лишают печ**е**нья. 
А обесп**е**чение - когда вместо дровяной п**е**чки ставят газовую плиту. И освобождают от необходимости п**е**чься о хлебе насущном.

Про "тухлость" аргумента о сведении всего и вся к единой якобы норме Вам уже сказали.

Comment: Согласен с этимологическим объяснением! Только вывод спорный. В случае "обеспЕчения" - Вы становитесь рабом Газпрома и печётесь о хлебе насущном, так, что не хватает средств уже и на печение. Опять приходим к "обеспечЕнию". А про "тухлость": речь не о НОРМЕ (это к "юристам"-бюрократам от языка), а про парадигму, которая в языке живет сама без Ваших указиловок. И народ будет ТАК произносить, КАК это естественно для языка, а не как Вы ему будете навязывать вопреки языковым законам.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант *обеспечЕние* гораздо легче произносить : бесперебОйное обеспечЕние.
Сабж произошел от глагола *обеспечить*; последний, в свою очередь, ведет свое происхождение от старинного глагола *печься* (заботиться) :

> ПЕЧЬСЯ
> пекУсь, печЁшься, пекУтся, прош. пёкся, пеклАсь, несов., о ком-чем (книжн.). Заботиться, иметь попечение о ком-чем-н. (Словарь Ушакова)

Как видим, ударение в личных формах "убегает" из корня, но это абсолютно никого не волнует! В *попечЕнии* та же самая картина : ударение сместилось, но никто не сомневается в корне, да и зачем? Родственные и семантически очень близкие *попечЕние* и *обеспечЕние* широко употребляются в СРЯ. Нет никаких причин в их различном произношении (ударение на суффикс в одном, на корень - в другом).

Comment: Иногда семантика, то есть сохранение связи с корнем, имеет значение, например: упорЯдочить - упорЯдочение, упрОчить - упрОчение. В первом слове дополнительно сохраняется центральное ударение, а во втором можно корень ПРОЧ принять, к примеру, за приставку ПРО, семантика корня неясно прочитывается.

Comment: Есть всякого рода исключения и различения (глАжение, ведЕние/вЕдение, видЕние/вИдение и тп). Но попечЕние/обеспечЕние следует уравнять в правах на суффиксальное ударение. И двух форм-значений в *обеспечении* не нужно.  
Печь - печЕние, печЕнье.  
Норма *обеспЕчение* безвозвратно устарела, как *музЫка* и *равЕнство*...

Answer (score 1):

Слово обеспЕчение происходит от слова "беспечный", а именно человек, у которого нет печи, т.е. нет хозяйства и, следовательно, нет никаких забот. Обеспечить - лишить печки, т.е. каких-либо забот. И ударение на второй слог правильнее! (Например, обезвОживание, обезврЕживание, обеззарАживание).

Comment: ОбезвОживание, обезврЕживание, обеззарАживание -  и т.п. это неуместные примеры, т.к. суффикс не -ЕНИ, а -ИВАНИ. А на него ударение и не обязательно должно падать. Спасибо!

Comment: Я, конечно, не такой специалист, но все-таки, какая разница какой суффикс, если во всех случаях ударение падает на корень. Просто по аналогии с приведенными мною примерами должно быть обеспЕчение. Хорошо, пожалуйста Вам другой пример: обесцвЕчение, обесцЕнение. Да, есть такие формы глаголов в словаре!

Comment: Интересные у Вас рассуждения о происхождении слова "беспечный". А Вы с другими славянскими языками знакомы? Например, с польским или чешским? В чешском есть слово bezpečnost, означающее "безопасность", как Вы видите в нём используется тот же самый славянский корень "печ", только речь здесь идёт не о выпечке, а совсем о другом.

Answer (score 0):

А что, в принципе,  вас смущает? Это т. н. вариативность в языке. И она, кстати, наблюдается давно. Можете прочитать здесь:

[9. ВАРИАНТНОСТЬ В ЯЗЫКЕ | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_9_var/)

Comment: В статье указано, что существование двух норм - это этап развития, в результате которого должна закрепиться одна форма (или, как вариант, должно утвердиться их смысловое различие). Итак, кто тут новый/прогрессивный и старый/консервативный? Вот словарь Аванесова (1987 год): обеспЕчение, не рек. обеспечЕние. Всё ясно, направление развития  определено - это переход ударения на суффикс ЕНИ как живое развитие языка при отсутствии причин сохранять его на корневой гласной глагола . Поэтому для существительного со значением действия прогрессивной является форма обеспечЕние.