# Почему «попечЕние», но «обеспЕчение»?

Tags: орфоэпия

Насчет новомодного ударения "обеспЕчение". Как будем произносить попЕчение или все-таки попечЕние? Например, фразы "у нее на попЕчении", "на попЕчении государства"?  Смешно звучит.

Comment: Насчет ударения в слове *обеспечение* см: ”https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35162/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%95%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%95%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не "обеспечЕние", а "обеспЕчение"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35162/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%95%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%95%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: @Aer Все-таки вопрос об ударении в слове «обеспечение», а про попечение - это аргумент в споре.

Comment: @М_Г в таком случае его необходимо закрыть. (Но его можно трактовать и как вопрос о *попечении* в связи с обеспечением.)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: @Aer Я бы оставил как вопрос о сравнении ударений в словах обеспечение и попечение

Answer (score 1):

Грамота.ру после обзора словарей [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=253836) делает следующее заключение:

> Таким образом, можно сделать следующие выводы. Употребление варианта обеспЕчение соотвествует строгой литературной норме современного русского языка. Вариант же обеспечЕние только завоевывает себе место под солнцем: пока лишь некоторые словари решились признать его допустимым (при этом в качестве основного все равно указывая вариант обеспЕчение). По-видимому, со временем варианты обеспЕчение и обеспечЕние станут равноправными (это естественный процесс: литературной норме свойственна динамика). Однако сейчас предпочтительным следует признать вариант обеспЕчение.

Comment: О**беспЕч**ение дарует **беспЕч**ную жизнь подопечным:)

Comment: Будьте добры, расскажите об ударении в слове "попечение".